# I really like the ruby way of allowing "isACar?" method names, but how to do it in js?

Tags: javascript

I know one way but is not practical:

```
var a = {'isACar?': function(){}}
a['isACar?']()
```

I would like something like this

```
a.isACar?()
```

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Why? If this was a syntactic sugar, it would still be strange, but it's even less than that - it's just a minor change in how functions are displayed.

Comment: My initial thought on seeing this question is "wow, a programming language lets you use ? in an identifier, ew!"

Comment: @JamesThorpe: it actually only lets you use ? in methods.  Not variables.  I'm not sure why.  It's not that weird though.  Most LISP variants allow anything besides whitespace, parentheses, and a few other things in identifiers.

Comment: @olleicua thanks for the info.  I need to find time to investigate some of the languages unfamiliar to me, at least so I know when they might be useful...

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to access a property with a question mark in the name using dot-notation in JavaScript, it starts a ternary operator.

Answer (score 5):

You **cannot** do this in javascript . The `?` character will be interpreted as a [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) operator .

> An identifier must start with $, _, or any character in the Unicode categories “Uppercase letter (Lu)”, “Lowercase letter (Ll)”, “Titlecase letter (Lt)”, “Modifier letter (Lm)”, “Other letter (Lo)”, or “Letter number (Nl)”.
>
> The rest of the string can contain the same characters, plus any U+200C zero width non-joiner characters, U+200D zero width joiner characters, and characters in the Unicode categories “Non-spacing mark (Mn)”, “Spacing combining mark (Mc)”, “Decimal digit number (Nd)”, or “Connector punctuation (Pc)”.

From [Valid JavaScript variable names](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-identifiers)

But on the bright side , you can have evil names for your variables like this :

```
var ಠ_ಠ = eval;
// or
var π = Math.PI;
```

Comment: You could choose an arbitrary unicode character to stand for a ?, e.g. ʃ: function isCoolʃ() { return true; }

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done... sorta.  The problem is that in javascript the question mark is used for inline if.  That said, if you're doing something with a truthy thing anyway you're probably going to be using it in a test of some sort, so the inline if may work for you.  For example:

```
var c = {};
c.isACar = function(){dosomethinghere};
var d = c.isACar()? 5 : 23;
```

Sets d to 5 iff c is a car, and to 23 otherwise.